# Workbox - NetworkOnly executes even if I return false

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox

Using Workbox, I am trying to deal with graphql.

Anyone know why I am getting this error message from `NetworkOnly`? I am returning `false` in the route matcher, so I don't know why `new NetworkOnly()` is even executing. This only happens in offline mode (no network available).

> The strategy could not generate a response for ... The underlying error is TypeError: Failed to fetch.

> at NetworkOnly._handle (webpack://service-workers/./node_modules/workbox-strategies/NetworkOnly.js?:101:19)
> at async NetworkOnly._getResponse (webpack://service-workers/./node_modules/workbox-strategies/Strategy.js?:155:24)

```
const bgSyncPlugin = new BackgroundSyncPlugin('myQueueName', {
  maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60 
});
 
const isGraphqlSubmitForm = async(event) => {
  const clonedRequest = event.request.clone();
  const body = await clonedRequest.json();

  if (body?.operationName === 'submitForm') {
    return true;
  }
  return false; // I MADE SURE THIS IS BEING RETURNED 
};
 
registerRoute(
  isGraphqlSubmitForm,
  new NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [bgSyncPlugin]
  }),
  'POST'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that—you're seeing that behavior because the [truthiness of the return value from this function](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-routing#:%7E:text=the%20only%20limitation%20is%20that%20the%20%22match%22%20callback%20must%20synchronously%20return%20a%20truthy%20value%2C%20you%20can%E2%80%99t%20perform%20any%20asynchronous%20work.%20the%20reason%20for%20this%20is%20that%20the%20router%20must%20synchronously%20respond%20to%20the%20fetch%20event%20or%20allow%20falling%20through%20to%20other%20fetch%20events.) is used to determine whether a route matches, and an `async` function always returns a `Promise`, which is a "truthy" value.

There's a [log message](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/blob/bbaa0bb5bc7830543be4f170d108842dd1f19e01/packages/workbox-routing/src/Router.ts#L315-L324) that warns about this if you're in Workbox's development mode.

If it's possible for you to add in a header on the requests you want to match, that would probably be the easiest way to synchronously trigger your route, since any attempt to access a request body needs to be `async`. Failing that, the cleanest approach would be to just match all of your GraphQL requests with a given route, and then inside of that route's handler, use whatever `async` logic you need to trigger different strategies for different types of traffic.